# I had a post recommended to be moved to ServerFault even though SO had tags for it

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Concerning this question - https://serverfault.com/questions/605052/gateway-timeout-caused-by-security-certificate

As I state in my comment there, I wonder why the tags would be here because there are no programming questions that could be asked about the things I have tagged? (Well, maybe a little bit about programming, but very little it seems so me - because editing config files doesn't seem much like programming.)

Why are tags for Ubuntu, Apache and SSL available at SO?

EDIT: I changed the link to the question on SF as I am deleting the question on SO.

Comment: You can ask plenty of programming questions concerning Apache; say you need to code an extension module. You can ask questions on how to drive the Ubuntu package system from Python, say, or how to build a C library with specific packages. You can ask how to speak the SSL protocol from your Ruby program. Those tags have meaning for *those types of questions*.

Comment: The presence of tags is not a reliable indicator of question topicality.  You have to look at the actual scope of the question itself.  The purpose of tags is to categorize questions, not identify on-topic subject areas.

Comment: Ah - thanks for clearing that up. It's late on a Friday and I'd rather leave the server problems behind. So I should just delete the one on SO and let it run its course on SF.